# How to get top 10 record group wise in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

How to get top 10 record group wise in oracle database?
In my query I am getting output from joining multiple table.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide datamodel and describe the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
  select some_column_you_didnt_tell_us,
         other_column_you_didnt_tell_us,
         row_number() over (partition by group_column_you_didnt_tell_us) as rn
  from the_table_you_didnt_tell_us
) t
where rn <= 10;
```

Comment: It gives only top 10 record. Not top 10 records of each group.

Comment: @Mayur Did you replace the `group_column_you_didnt_tell_us` with the "correct" columns that you need to define "a group".